# Using file content as object data

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I'm trying to send a http request using `formData` from a .json file but can't get the data to add into the `options` object correctly.

```
{"name":"charlie","age":"20"}
```

Below is what I've got going at the moment.

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + directory, (error, data) => { 
  if(error) {throw error;}
  data = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data))

  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'https://google.com',
    formData: data
  };

  .............

});
```

This isn't working as I intend as it's seeing `data` as a string putting apostrophe's around the content. I've tried to use `Object.assign` but again I run into the issue that my `data` is seen as a string.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been trying to research this for the past 2 hours and haven't had much luck. 
If you have any recommendations on a better system or package other than request.js I'd be happy to hear.
Thanks again for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is.... formData: needs an variable with Formdata as his Datatype:
this should work :)

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile("C:/tes/test.json", (error, data) => { 
    if(error) {throw error;}
    let fdata = FormData()
    console.log(data)
    data = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data.name)

    fdata.append("name", data.name)
    fdata.append("age", data.age)

    var options = {
      'method': 'GET',
      'url': 'https://google.com',
      formData: fdata
    };
  });
```

Comment: Doesn't exactly work as intended. See Pastebin for results https://pastebin.com/Q0NFLZEm